Конвертация hdmi в Gpio пин рабери
У меня есть Gpio дисплей для Raspberry PI. Хотел узнать есть возможны способы конвертации hdmi в Gpio что бы использовать свой дисплей для пк

Или может кто знает каким образом можно сделать hdmi дисплей для пк 5 дюймов, желательно недорого

вам нужен переносной дисплей для непереносного компьютера?  зачем?

Я хочу сделать настольный дисплей для вывода доп инфы и он будет сенсорный, Я хочу на него перетащить какое нибудь окно и было удобно смотреть и работать. В этом суть моей идеи

купите обычный 15" сенсорный дисплей за 10 тыр..  куда ещё дешевле-то?

Не очень понятно, что значит GPIO, но скорее всего при наличии драйвера в ядре всё решается через запуск X Server.
